How do I Show that $\exists a, \forall e > 0; a < e \Rightarrow a \le 0$
When proving using contradiction,can the method specified below be used.
lets assume that $\forall a, \exists e > 0; a < e$ and $a > 0$
since the condition holds for all 'a', let $a=2e$
then $2e<e$, $2<1$. Which is a contradiction.
therefore $\exists a, \forall e > 0; a < e \Rightarrow a \le 0$.
Can I know where i might have gone wrong and if not, whether theres another method to prove it.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

This is hard to follow.  Your first statement, "For all $a$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $a<\epsilon$ and $a>0$"  Is trivially false as stated, since not all $a$ are positive.  So, presumably you meant "$a>0$" as an assumption, not a conclusion.  But then, the point is "there exists $\epsilon$ with $a<\epsilon$" which is clearly true...just take $\epsilon=a+1$.  The fact that some other choice for $\epsilon$ fails (you pick $\epsilon=\frac a2$ for example) is irrelevant.

I suggest:  write mathematical statements out using English words, not logical symbols.  I think those symbols are confusing you.

Because you are not using MathJax,
which is straightforward to learn, your posted analysis has a typo.  If you edit your posted analysis to read $$\cdots ~a = \dfrac{e}{2},~~\text{then} ~~\dfrac{e}{2} < e, ~~\dfrac{1}{2} < 1.$$ then your analysis is valid.

What you want to show is: if a constant $a$ is smaller than any arbitrary positive number, then it must be non-positive, that is, $a \leq 0$. The problem is that the statement in logical notation in the problem title is not well written. It states that "if there exists an $a$ such that for all $e$ greater than zero, $a < e$, then $a \leq 0$". Even though it is correct, the truth is that this statement is true even with the $\forall$ quantifier on $a$, that is: "for all $a$, if for all $e$ greater than zero, $a < e$, then $a \leq 0$. In logical notation, that would be:
$$\forall a((\forall e>0 ,\: a< e)\implies a \leq 0)$$
and its negation would be:
$$\lnot(\forall a((\forall e>0 ,\: a< e)\implies a \leq 0)) = \exists a,\{\lnot[(\forall e>0 ,\: a< e)\implies a \leq 0]\}$$
now notice that the negation sign is applying to an implication statement, so it yields: $\lnot (a \implies b) = \lnot (b \lor (\lnot a)) = (\lnot b \land (\lnot \lnot a))= (\lnot b \land a)$, that is
$$ \exists a [\lnot(a \leq 0)\land ((\forall e>0,e>a))] = \exists a,[(a > 0)\land (\forall e>0,e>a)] \label{eq1}\tag{*}$$
Which reads "there exists a number $a$ which is positive and smaller than all positive numers at the same time. This can be proven a contradiction trivially since $a$ satisfies $a>0$, and in order for \ref{eq1} to be true, $a$ would have to satisfy $a > a$, which is impossible.
In your proof, you obtained the expression $\forall a,((\exists e > 0, a> e)\land (a > 0)$ which also isn't well written, because there are  $a$'s which contradict the statement by simply being smaller than zero. And bessides than that, in all statements of the kind "for all $a$ [...], there exists $b$ [...]", there is implicitly a dependance of $b$ on $a$, that is for any given $a$, a $b$ can  be obtained. So you can't pick $a = 2e$ because the existance of $e$ is conditioned to the particularity of $a$.
So I recommend, as @lulu commented, you write the mathematical statements using english words (or whichever is your native language) and pay attention to the established dependence on "for all $a$, there exists $b$" statements. One hint is to use a subscript to stress this dependance: $\forall a[...],\exists b_a [...]$. Such $b_a$ may not be unique, but it cannot be stated if $a$ isn't defined.

Be careful when using both existential and universal quantifiers as you can’t swap their order ! For example your first statement is “for all $a$, it exists some $e$ such that blabla”. In this sentence, the element $e$ depends on $a$ ! I’ll give you an analogy : for all human x, it exists a human y such that y is the father of x, but it is not true that it exists a human y such that for all human x, y is the father of x (we do not all have the same father!). So in your proof, setting $a=2e$ is a nonsense as $e$ depends on $a$ so you can’t use $e$ to set $a$ in the first place.
